# Webgl shader debugger, variable inspection

Tags: javascript, debugging, opengl-es, webgl

I am looking for a javascript which allows me to debug a WebGL shader down to the single line / variable level.
So it should be possible break on every line and inspect the value of every variable.

This can be done by instrumentation (parsing the shader, generating a shader which outputs the requested variable, execute this shader against the current context and returns the ouput to the user)

It is similar to what glslDevil (http://www.vis.uni-stuttgart.de/glsldevil/) does for OpenGL.

Does anyone know if such a tool for WebGL exists ?

Comment: The tool I imagine would be very ambitious. 1. GLSL code would be compiled w/ GLSL debug info by library/driver. 2. GPU would relegate a single monitored thread to each shader and trap on breakpoint instructions. 3. GPU monitor would then send GPU state info back to CPU on each trap. Hmmm.. probably good reason this doesn't exist. Probably just have to simulate GLSL code on CPU to pull this off...

Comment: I was thinking to do it with software instrumentation only. As long as the driver / implementation subsystem can handle the complexity of some extra ifs, you should be able to do it completely in software.

Comment: I see the latest version for [glsldevil](http://wwwvis.informatik.uni-stuttgart.de/glsldevil/index.html#downloads) is from 2010? This seems like an important gap to fill.

Comment: Open source fork of glsldevil : http://glsl-debugger.github.io/

Comment: forked version looks nice ... looks like they need someone to work in the OS X version -- hmmm... maybe I'll check it out.

Comment: Not sure if its worth saying, but one of my side projects is creating this for WebGL as a chrome extension similar to the WebGL Inspector. Haven't got too far with it yet, though.

Answer (score 1):

Firefox, at at least **v38**, has a debugging panel for WebGL GLSL shaders.  You are able to edit and quickly recompile them for debugging purposes.  I don't believe it allows for breakpoints in individual lines though.

You can enable it through the gear panel:

[image: Firefox Gear panel]

And then use it in the Shader Editor panel

[image: Shader Editor Panel]